# VS2010 database projects - global system objects that have a user database reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-project

I have something like the following in a VS2010 database project:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM [$(MyOtherDB)].sys.tables
```

In other words referencing a global system object via a user database reference.  I’ve set up references to `master.dbschema` from both the containing project and MyOtherDB project and a reference from the containing project to MyOtherDB project, but I’m still getting *SQL04151* warnings.  There is some more information about it in this thread (where Gert Drapers seems to confirm that it’s a bug): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/914c8560-f9c3-40b6-9275-5df48baef9b1.

> This seems like to bug to me. The object inside the master.dbschema
>   file is marked as GloballyScoped which means it lives inside the
>   global namespace, which should imply that you can reference it using
>   in the following ways:
>
> 1. [master].[sys].[objects]
> 2. [userdb].[sys].[objects]
> 3. [sys].[objects]
>
> Option 2 clearly does not work while it should.

I couldn’t find any other references to this scenario via Google.  I was just wondering if anyone had come across this and knew of any fixes or work-arounds?

Comment: See if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568548/vs-2010-build-database-project-receive-sql04151

Comment: Thanks @Kaf, but I'm afraid that doesn't really cover my scenario.  I have a cross database reference to a global system object.